# Block Emoji from being inserted into text field

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a text field for user input, but only allows a limited character set. Blocking keyboard characters works fine using `keydown` to first vet the keystroke, then `event.preventDefault()` if it doesn't pass.

Windows has an Emoji menu which can be activated by `WIN+Period` or right click. The menu allows the user to click on Emoji icons and have them inserted into the text field.

This event can be captured via `Input` and the character is shown in `event.data` for vetting. What I cannot resolve though is how to block the action `event.preventDefault()` does not stop this.

Here's an example of the type of code I've tried.

```
textbox.addEventListener( "input", event => {
 if ( event.data === BAD ) {
  event.preventDefault();
 }
}, false);
```

Digging into the `event` data I see that `cancelable` is `false`, whereas for `keydown` it's `true`.

Is there a perhaps another event other than `input` to capture this is earlier?

Comment: The emoji picker is a feature of Windows 10, not Chrome. So I don't think this question is specific to Chrome at all.

Instead of trying to prevent the input, why not filter out what you don't want and update the value of the input?

Comment: Dang! @jdgregson beat me to the punch on that!

Comment: @CoryCoolguy I thought you beat me, so I deleted my answer :P

Comment: Ah, because I saw on the Chrome blog I presumed it was a Chrome feature it https://blog.chromium.org/2018/06/chrome-68-beta-add-to-home-screen.html so @CoryCoolguy you're suggesting I remove the emojis once added rather than look to block them beforehand?

Comment: That's what makes the most sense to me. Let's say the user pastes in the following string:
"Stack Overflow is LIT "
If you cancel the the input, none of it would get entered, right? I could be wrong, but that's the functionality I'd expect from that solution. So instead, I suggest you go through the value and remove characters you don't want whenever the input event is fired.

Comment: I like @CoryCoolguy's approach. And since the emoji library is constantly growing, you might have better luck only allowing things that you do want rather than blocking a list of Emojis. This might make it difficult to input other unicode characters, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on @CoryCoolguy's suggestion one solution is to remove characters from the text field after they're entered by checking the contents of the field.

This solution uses a regex validator to locate any characters that are not part of a valid set, then replace them with a blank character.

```
textbox.addEventListener( "input", event => {
 textbox.value = textbox.value.replace( /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/gm, '');
}, false);

textbox.addEventListener( "paste", event => {
 textbox.value = textbox.value.replace( /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/gm, '');
}, false);
```

Using the `input` event, each time a character is typed or inserted via the Windows Emoji panel the value of the text box is scanned and any characters not matching the regex is removed.

Adding a `paste` event listener will monitor anything pasted from the clipboard and will allow the contents to be pasted before removing any unwanted characters. This means that if there's a mix of valid and non-valid character in the clipboard, then the valid ones will still get pasted.

Comment: Handling the paste event doesn't hurt, but as far as I can tell it works just fine with only the input event being handled. Which makes sense, because 1) pasting something in _is_ inputting something, and 2) your regex isn't just replacing the last character or string entered, but the entire value (which I agree is the best approach).

Comment: But this way you are not only blocking emojis but also any non ASCII chars.